# How to create a vector in Matlab with two different step sizes?

Tags: matlab, vector, size

I want to create a vector in Matlab with two step sizes that will alternate.

```
vector =
           0  50  51  101 102 152 etc.
```

So the step size is 50 and 1 which will alternate. How to write a script that will create this vector?

Comment: So my vector can be made with two vecotors:    0  50  50  100  100  150 and 0  0  1  1  2  2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
N = 6; %// Number of elements needed in the final output
sz1 = 50; %// Stepsize - 1
sz2 = 4; %// Stepsize - 2
startval = 8; %// First element of the output
vector = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,[startval startval+sz1]',[0:N/2-1]*(sz1+sz2)),1,[])
```

**Output**

```
vector =
     8    58    62   112   116   166
```

**Note:** For your problem, you need to use `sz2 = 1` and `startval = 0` instead.

**Explanation**

Internally it creates two matrices which when "flattened-out" to form vectors would resemble the two vectors that you have pointed out in the comments. You can get those two matrices with the following two sets of conditions.

**Set #1:** If you keep `N = 6`, `sz1 = 50`, `sz2 = 0` and `startval = 0` -

```
bsxfun(@plus,[startval startval+sz1]',[0:N/2-1]*(sz1+sz2))
```

gives us -

```
 0    50   100
50   100   150
```

**Set #2:** If you keep `N = 6`, `sz1 = 0`, `sz2 = 1` and `startval = 0` -

```
bsxfun(@plus,[startval startval+sz1]',[0:N/2-1]*(sz1+sz2))
```

gives us -

```
 0     1     2
 0     1     2
```

Good thing about `bsxfun` is that these two matrices can be summed internally to give the final output -

```
 0    51   102
50   101   152
```

Since, you needed the output as a vector, we need to flatten it out using `reshape` -

```
reshape(...,1,[])
```

giving us -

```
 0    50    51   101   102   152
```

Thus, we have the final code that was listed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas I've been playing around with:

Initialization (comparable to Divakar's answer):

```
N = 6; %// Number of pairs in the final output
firstStep = 50;
secndStep = 1; 
startVal = 8; %// First element of the output
```

And then:

```
%// Idea 1:
V1 = [startVal cumsum(repmat([firstStep,secndStep],[1,N])) + startVal];

%// Idea 2:
trimVec = @(vec)vec(1:end-1);
V2 = trimVec(circshift(kron((startVal:firstStep:startVal + ...
               N*firstStep),[1,1]),[0,-1]) + kron((0:N),[1,1]));
```

Note that both of these vectors result in length = 2*N + 1.

The thing I'd like to point out is that if you create your vector of differences (e.g. `[1 50 1 50 ...]`), [`cumsum()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) really does the trick from there (you can also have more than 2 step sizes if you choose).

Answer (score 0):

Let the input data be

```
step1 = 50;
step2 = 1;
start = 0;
number = 9; %// should be an odd number
```

Then:

```
n = (number-1)/2;
vector = cumsum([start reshape(([repmat(step1,1,n); repmat(step2,1,n)]),1,[])]);
```

The result in this example is

```
vector =
     0    50    51   101   102   152   153   203   204
```